# Best way to integrate angular-google-maps to an AngularJS and ES6 project through import statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am working on front-end of a project and using Angular v-1.5 and ES6 in this project. I am trying to integrate gMaps API into the project.

As there's no official documentation available from google for ES6 as of now, I am using **angular-google-maps** ([link](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/)) by angular-ui([link](http://angular-ui.github.io/)) to do the same.

However, the problem is I couldn't find any examples or solid material to do the same. 
I tried to do it through the obvious way, we do it in ES6, i.e. npm install followed by importing it into our app. But it doesn't work out. Turns out that I can't import lodash.

See the issue with lodash:

a) https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1457

b) https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1704

I tried these solutions mentioned in comments by one of the contributor of lodash:

a) https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1704#issuecomment-164379884

b) https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1704#issuecomment-164524426

but they are not working.

I still can't find anything on internet that solves this issue. I am getting the error:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined**

which is obviously due to missing lodash constant ( _ )

If nothing works out I, unfortunately, have to roll back to ES5 which would again consume a lot of time as I will have to change the structure of the project and change the entire syntax to ES5.

I am facing this exact same problem.
See [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1937):

My **app.js** file:

```
import angular from 'angular';

// Import our app config files
import constants  from './config/app.constants';
import appConfig  from './config/app.config';
import appRun     from './config/app.run';

import 'angular-ui-router';

import 'angular-ui-bootstrap';

import 'angular-google-maps';

import fp from 'lodash/fp';
const _ = fp();

// Import our templates file (generated by Gulp)
import './config/app.templates';
// Import our app functionaity
import './layout';
import './components';
import './home';
import './profile';
import './services';
import './auth';
import './settings';
import './dashboard';
import './maps';


// Create and bootstrap application
const requires = [
  'ui.router',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'uiGmapgoogle-maps',
  '_',
  'templates',
  'app.layout',
  'app.components',
  'app.home',
  'app.profile',
  'app.article',
  'app.services',
  'app.auth',
  'app.settings',
  'app.dashboard',
  'app.map'
];

// Mount on window for testing
window.app = angular.module('app', requires);

angular.module('app').constant('AppConstants', constants);

angular.module('app').config(appConfig);

angular.module('app').run(appRun);

angular.bootstrap(document, ['app'], {
  strictDi: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include/load(via webpack) lodash: quickest way is to include this in your html:

```
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.15.0/lodash.min.js'> </script>
```

I'm also having some issues getting it to work correctly with ES6, there is a issue posted on github: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1929